# Send list of objects using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, list, httpclient

I am communicating with an endpoint created by another team in asp.net core that accepts ([FromBody] Applicant applicant)

The applicant object looks like this:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public string FirstName{get; set;}
    public string LastName{get; set;}
    
    public List<Reports> Reports{get; set;}
}
```

and the list of reports is from this object:

```
public class Reports
{
    public string ReportName {get;set;}
    public byte[] ReportFile {get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to call the endpoint twice where a send an applicant with one reportfile
and a second time where I send an applicant with two report files. This is what I have so far:

```
byte[] report1 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report1");
byte[] report2 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report2");
byte[] report3 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report3");


var reportOjbect = new
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Reports = new []
    {
        new {
            ReportName = "6 week Report",
            ReportFile = report1
        }

    }

};

var baseUrl = "localhost:1111";
var endpoint = "/api/validate-reports";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(reportOjbect.FirstName), "FirstName");
content.Add(new StringContent(reportOjbect.LastName), "LastName");
//How to add list of reports here that contain both the report name and the report file
    
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}{endpoint}")
{ Content = content};

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception($"Failed to send email: {response.StatusCode}");
}    
return Results.Ok("Reports were processed");
```

How do I add a list of reports to the content object.

Comment: In general you want to create Applicant objects. Each of these applicants would have their reports you want to send (one or two reports). Then you serialize those  objects and send them.  I suppose you could try to build json directly (which is what you seem to be doing here) but ordinarily you serialize the objects with a json library - i.e. the built in .net json library or with newtonsoft.json.

Comment: @topsail, this is the case even when sending a file/byte[]?

Comment: Yes, your `Applicant` class has a field that is a byte array - it will serialize as a byte array (feel free to prove me wrong but I don't see why it wouldn't).

Comment: *"asp.net core that accepts (`[FromBody] Applicant applicant`)"* - better off to send a json object instead of doing multipart form submission. keep in mind however, `byte[]` in `json` will be represented as `base64` which is quite expensive (~1.5 of the original size). you also have to watchout for maximum [request size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded).

Comment: Have you read [this article](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-multipart-form-data-in-httpclient/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding new class ReportData instead of anonymous object and serialized it when sending it out to client application

New Class:

```
public class ReportData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Reports[] Reports { get; set; }
}
```

and your function will be updated as:

```
byte[] report1 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report1");
byte[] report2 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report2");
byte[] report3 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is a test report3");

var a = new ReportData() { FirstName = "", LastName = "" };

var reportOjbect = new ReportData()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Reports = new Reports[]
    {
        new Reports
        {
            ReportName = "6 week Report",
            ReportFile = report1
        }
    }

};

var baseUrl = "localhost:1111";
var endpoint = "/api/validate-reports";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(reportOjbect.FirstName), "FirstName");
content.Add(new StringContent(reportOjbect.LastName), "LastName");
content.Add(new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(reportOjbect.Reports)), "Reports");
```

Lets try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Put your reports in a List<byte[]>.

```
var reports = new List<byte[]> 
{
  report1,
  report2,
  report3
};
```

Then use .Select()

```
reportObject.Reports = reports.Select(r => new[]
  {
    ReportName = "6 week Report",
    ReportFile = report1
  }).ToArray();
```